# Can we add description field on the Milestone related layout of the case?

Tags: apex, casemilestone, entitlements

I have developed the `Entitlement Process and Milestones` show below in the screen shot. Here I dont have any description saying that which `Milestones` are running for what ? Can we add the `description` field in this `layout`, so that `Agent` can understand for which `Processes/steps` these `milestones` are running ?

[image]

Here for a single case I can have 10 active milestones running, then I dont have any way to differentiate which milestones are running for which processes?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a tracking kind of object which will take values from Milestone object and that will give you much better flexibility.

Similar approach I have already done earlier.

Like, if you like to track how long a case is sitting on different status that will also help you, which you are unable for track with the Milestones record only. Milestones are good for tracking respecting business hours but having same name for different milestones that will not help you in reporting purpose.

Approach will be like this:

1. When you create a milestone record, create a record in Tracking  object where you will add case status, case owners and all milestone level information.
2. Similarly, when milestone is getting closed, you will update relevant record in that tracking object.

[image: case tracking]

I guess, you are thinking about smaller pieces rather than entire design.

Comment: Could you provide code to support your answer will be great !

Comment: you could take a stab and post in a separate question